# Find #REF in Row and Delete Cell

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have a spreadsheet in Excel 2010 that sometimes has a reference error. I want to clear the cell in that particular row; ie. Clear any cells in Row 7 that contains a reference error. I'm having some trouble with it.

```
Sub Check_Ref()

Dim rng As Range
Dim rngError As Range
Dim cell as 'something

Set rng = Sheets("All Projects").Range("AE7:AK7")

Dim rngError As Range
Set rngError = rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors)

If Not rngError Is Nothing Then
    For Each cell In rngError
        'Clear the cell
    Next
End If

End Sub
```

This is what I have so far. I don't know how to actually clear the cell. Any help would be great.

Comment: Try `cell.clearcontents`.

Comment: You should be able to avoid the `For Each` loop and just use `rngError.ClearContents`

Comment: You can define the `cell` variable as a `Range`

Comment: Agree with @Degustaf. Also Please pad up `Set rngError = rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors)` between `On Error Resume Next` and `On Error GoTo 0` so that you do not get an error if no formula error cells were found

Comment: BTW you also have `Dim rngError As Range` declared twice.. A typo perhaps?

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you. I defined `cell` as `Variant` and that seems to work fine. And yes, that is a typo.

Comment: You don't need to use cell at all. see the suggestion by @Degustaf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No loop is required:

```
Sub Check_Ref()

   Dim rng As Range
   Dim rngError As Range

   Set rng = Sheets("All Projects").Range("AE7:AK7")
   Set rngError = rng.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors)

   If Not rngError Is Nothing Then
       rngError.Clear
   End If

End Sub
```

**EDIT#1**

Disable error if no errors found on worksheet:

```
Sub Check_Ref()

   Dim rng As Range
   Dim rngError As Range

   Set rng = Sheets("All Projects").Range("AE7:AK7")
   On Error Resume Next
       Set rngError = rng.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors)
   On Error GoTo 0
   If Not rngError Is Nothing Then
       rngError.ClearContents
   End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Just a note: I believe if you choose to use `rngError.Clear` instead of `rngError.ClearContents`, any special formatting you had in that cell will also be deleted.

Comment: @MattCremeens  Fixed as per your suggestion!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Given you want to isolate `#REF` errors would suggest you are more specific with how you handle the `xlErrors` retruned from SpecialCells:

```
Sub Check_Err()

Dim rng As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim rngError As Range

Set rng = Sheets("All Projects").Range("AE7:AK7")
On Error Resume Next
Set rngError = rng.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors)
On Error GoTo 0
If Not rngError Is Nothing Then
    For Each rng2 In rngError
       If rng2.Value2 = CVErr(xlErrRef) Then rng2.ClearContents
    Next
End If
End Sub
```